# Is it possible to prevent emails being sent from an address absent from the AD user's account?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003

I'm using Exchange Server 2003 on a Windows Server 2003 which is also a domain controller. If a client connects through SMTP using his AD username and password, he can send email from any email address, and not just the email addresses listed in said user's AD account.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening, by rejecting an email submitted to SMTP if the connection is authenticated with an AD account and the from address is absent from that account?

Comment: Configure the client Outlook to use RPC over HTTP instead of POP/SMTP.